# How to get a list of equipment in MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to get a list of equipment from MS Graph. Preferably using the Go SDK, but even using a direct request would be good.

Getting the list of users works, and I see the equipment in there, but it is there among all the users and rooms, with no way to distinguish between the account types.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

        {
            "displayName": "Pradeep Gupta",
            "givenName": "Pradeep",
            "jobTitle": "Accountant",
            "mail": "PradeepG@asdvmd.onmicrosoft.com",
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Silent Room",
            "givenName": null,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "silent.room@asdvmd.onmicrosoft.com",
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Small Table",
            "givenName": null,
            "jobTitle": null,
            "mail": "small.table@asdvmd.onmicrosoft.com",
        }
```

(some fields omitted for brevity, but nothing that would identify the equipment (tables in this case) was there)

For getting rooms I use the Go SDK, and that works well:

```golang
g.userClient.Places().GraphRoom().Get(context.Background(), nil)
```

Direct request works just as well:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room
```

But that doesn't list equipment.

How to get that equipment?

Comment: Just wondering, what is "Equipment account type"? Do you have accounts for tables, chairs and alike? How are they supposed to log in? o_O

Comment: @Nikolay Yes, the tables have their e-mail address and no, they don't "log in". This is how Microsoft 365 handles bookings. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/room-and-equipment-mailboxes?view=o365-worldwide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the user's mailbox settings. [mailboxSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource type has property [userPurpose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0#:%7E:text=the%20user%27s%20mailbox.-,userPurpose,-userPurpose).

If the mail is associated with the room then the value of the `userPurpose` property is `room`, for the equipment the `userPurpose` is set to `equipment`.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/mailboxSettings
```

If you are using delegated permissions you will probably receive the `ErrorAccessDenied` error regardless you have the `MailboxSettings.Read` permission.

You should be able to read mailbox settings with the application permission `MailboxSettings.Read`.

Unfortunately, you cannot filter users by the mailbox settings

```
GET /v1.0/users?$filter=mailboxSettings/userPurpose+eq+'equipment'&$select=id,displayName,mail,mailboxSettings
```

So, you need to access mailbox settings one by one

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/mailboxSettings
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's unfortunate that i can't filter directly.

Comment: Is there a way to test the mailboxSettings endpoint in Graph Explorer? Can I access graphExplorer with app permissions?

Comment: Graph Explorer works with delegated permissions, so you can access only signed-in user https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailboxSettings with MailboxSettings.Read permission. For other users /v1.0/users/{other_user_id}/mailboxSettings you will get ErrorAccessDenied

Comment: Whenever I try to use the /users/ Endpoint to get Details about a room, it throws an error and says, that the "Requested User {id of the Room from /places Endpoint} is invalid. Why does that happen? I can list the room and see its details when using the /v1.0/places/microsoft.graph.room endpoint. Same goes for Equipment-Mailboxes. Can't see the details of those aswell...

Comment: @Ayibogan When using /users, you need to use room email, id of a room from /places is different from id of a room from /users. Only email matches